# How would i dynamically fetch a property from another controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I am currently working on some bread crumb for my application, in my current architecture, a controller can have a title property, which my Breadcrumb controller picks up on path changes.

This is my code.

```
MyApp.HomeBreadcrumbController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['application']
  app: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application')

  path: ( ->
    @controllerFor(@get('app.currentPath')).get('title')
  ).property('app.currentPath')
```

This works perfectly, the title is fetched from the current controller, but there is a problem, this is what i get if i look in the console.

```
DEPRECATION: Controller#controllerFor is deprecated, please use Controller#needs instead
```

I have tried to convert it, but no luck yet, is there any way i can do something similar to the provided?

My home route.

```
MyApp.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  renderTemplate: ->

    @render 'home/breadcrumbs',
      controller: 'homeBreadcrumb'
      outlet: 'beforeContent'
      into: 'application'

    @render()
```

And the breadcrumb.hbs

```
<div class="before-content blue-gradient">
    <div class="ui breadcrumb">
      <a class="section">{{path}}</a>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Does `@get('app.currentPath.title')` work?

Comment: Would be neat, but no :/

Comment: You can safely use `controllerFor` from a route, but not from a controller. To properly access other controllers from within a controller, you need to explicitly add them to the `needs` array so that Ember knows what dependencies to scope.

Comment: @MartinElvar Can you maybe show how the breadcrumbs are being placed within a template? This looks like you are just outputting a title property... As opposed to an array of titles that is iterated over within a template.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I know, but using needs instead of controllerFor prevents me for calling it dynamically. as i can't add controllers depending on the current route, like i do with the controllerFor.
I don't think i am outputting it wrong, never the less, i will update the question in a min.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I just started developing the breadcrumb, so first i just need to get the title, which i what i am trying to achieve, then i will add path with multiple title (In a array). I have added the template, and home route thought.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that if you were to do it without alias you should do:

```
this.get('controllers.application').get('currentPath').get('title')
```

I would say just try

```
@app.get('currentPath').get('title')
```

if the alias works the way it should then it should work.

Comment: Sadly id doesn't, it seems to me that the controllerFor method, evaluate the route to the controller. Where as in your example you are calling .get('title') on the string, that currentPath returns. Therefor the get method doesn't exist.

Comment: what about @get('app.currentPath').get('title') it seems weird because the method that works for you is getting title from currentPath

Comment: I tried just that, with no luck. I get Uncaught TypeError: Object home.blogs.index has no method 'get' where home.blogs.index is my route